# I am trying to extract data from mongodb using bottle in python and use d3.js to visualize it: Mongodb-->Python-->d3.js

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, d3.js, bottle

```
import bottle, pymongo  
from pymongo import MongoClient 
client = pymongo.MongoClient(some URI)  
db = client['database']  
dbcoll = db['collection']  
@bottle.route('/hello')  
def grab_record(name):  
    bottle.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'  
    return dbcoll.find_one({'_id':False})  
bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

On opening http://localhost:8080/hello, this is the error I get:

[image]

Both bottle.py and this file are on my Desktop. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The parameters in @bottle.route's URL must match the number of arguments in the function that follows it. In your case it doesn't. @bottle.route has no parameters but the function has one (name) argument.

You could either remove name e.g.

```
def grab_record():  
    bottle.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'  
    return dbcoll.find_one({'_id':False})
```

or alternatively change @bottle.route so that it takes a parameter e.g.

```
@bottle.route('/hello/<name>')
```

depending on your needs.

Comment: { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("kdahfa"), 
    "minTime" : ISODate("2016-04-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "maxTime" : ISODate("2016-04-02T00:11:00.000+0000"), 
    "Time" : 660.0, 
    "Name" : "Sam"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("aabhk"), 
    "minTime" : ISODate("2016-04-02T01:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "maxTime" : ISODate("2016-04-02T02:14:25.000+0000"), 
    "Time" : 4465.0, 
    "Name" : "Bob"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("bak"), 
    "minTime" : ISODate("2016-04-02T19:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "maxTime" : ISODate("2016-04-02T19:52:22.000+0000"), 
    "Time" : 3142.0, 
    "Name" : "Sam"
}

Comment: This the kind of data that I have. Now I wish to create a Gantt Chart from it on d3.js. First problem, gettin this data on the d3.js and . I am taking help from this example
http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5449641
Could you please help me here. Your answer helped me getting rid of the error! Thanks for that :)

Comment: As you might've guessed, I'm new to this!

Comment: The code that I've mentioned in the question is to extract the mongodb data to a url. I now wish to use this url to create a d3.js Gantt Chart.

Comment: @glitterati if you have new questions, ask them separately. I've answered the question you originally asked here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have asked the question seperately. Please answer if you know this. I have been stuck on this problem for days.

Comment: If you want people to answer your follow-up question, you should accept this answer if it solved the question you did ask.